# Understanding how to pass a variable to Routes in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hello I have a file for mongo functions in which I would like to pass a value produced by a function to the routes file but I am struggling to find a way to do so.

labels.js

```
const findLabels = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  const collection = db.collection(documentName);
  // Find some documents
  collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Found the following records");
    console.log(docs)

    callback(docs);
  });
}

module.exports = {

  findLabels: () => MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err)
    console.log('Connected successfully to server')

    const db = client.db(dbName)

    findLabels(db, function () {

      client.close()
    })
  })
}
```

I would like to pass docs to routes

routes.js

```
router.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
  db.findLabels()
  res.render('index')
})
```

Comment: ... use the callback that you defined.

Comment: Hey thanks for answer Kevin, I just started Javascript like two days ago, can you be more specific? How do I use the call back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the signature of the exported version of `findLabels()` to accept a callback function. Then you can nest your callbacks to create a control flow where `db.findLabels()` is passing `docs` all the way back to the route.

```
const findLabels = (db, cb) => {
  // Get the documents collection
  const collection = db.collection(documentName);

  // Find some documents
  collection.find({}).toArray((err, docs) => {
    // An error occurred we need to return that to the given 
    // callback function
    if (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }

    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Found the following records");
    console.log(docs)

    return cb(null, docs);
  });
}

module.exports = {
  findLabels: cb => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err)
      }

      console.log('Connected successfully to server')

      const db = client.db(dbName)

      findLabels(db, (err, docs) => {
        if (err) {
          return cb(err)
        }

        // return your documents back to the given callback
        return cb(null, docs)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Here's your router now passing the labels to your `index` route once they've been returned.

```
router.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
  db.findLabels((err, labels) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.sendStatus(500)
    }

    res.render('index', {labels})
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help pete, I tried it out and got this error "TypeError: cb is not a function" referring to "return cb(null, docs)"

Comment: @Ricky you need to make sure that your using the router example I gave.

Comment: thank you, I wasn't showing you the entire code base so some things got in the way but your solution works.